# How to create a LINQ Query with IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a task to implement a LINQ query that return IEnumerable<>.

```
/// <summary>
/// Calculates for each customer count of his orders.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The sequence of customers and how many orders each has.</returns>
public static IEnumerable<(string customerId, int orderCount)> CustomersOrdersCount()
{
    List<Customer> customers = Customers.CustomerList;
    IEnumerable<(string customerId, int orderCount)> query = from c in customers
                                                             from co in c.Orders
                                                             select (customerId: c.CustomerId, orderCount: (int)c.Orders.Length);

    return query;
}
```

(This is my implementation which does not work)

Below is Customers Class:

```
namespace Linq.DataSources
{
    public static class Customers
    {
        public static List<Customer> CustomerList { get; } =
            (from e in XDocument.Parse(InputValues.CustomersXml).Root?.Elements("customer")
                select new Customer
                {
                    CustomerId = (string) e.Element("id"),
                    CompanyName = (string) e.Element("name"),
                    Address = (string) e.Element("address"),
                    City = (string) e.Element("city"),
                    Region = (string) e.Element("region"),
                    PostalCode = (string) e.Element("postalcode"),
                    Country = (string) e.Element("country"),
                    Phone = (string) e.Element("phone"),
                    Orders = (
                        from o in e.Elements("orders").Elements("order")
                        select new Order
                        {
                            OrderId = (int) o.Element("id"),
                            OrderDate = (DateTime) o.Element("orderdate"),
                            Total = (decimal) o.Element("total")
                        }).ToArray()
                }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Orders class:

```
namespace Linq.DataSources
{
    public class Order
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
        
        public override string ToString() => $"{OrderId}: {OrderDate:d} for {Total:C2}";
    }
}
```

Basically, the task is to return (`Customer_Id`, How_Many_Orders_Each_Customer_Has)

Comment: Maybe I've overlooked something, but it should be as simple as `from c in customers
select (customerId: c.CustomerId, orderCount: c.Orders.Length)` (just without the `from` over c.Orders).

Comment: As say @Heinzi, just remove `from co in c.Orders`.

Comment: Don't use unnecessary casts: `Array.Length` is already `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I missed any detail but it should be straight forward. We dont need from co in c.orders  :-

```
 from c in customers                                                             
 select (customerId: c.CustomerId, orderCount: c.Orders.Length);
```